# how to add custom visualization to Media Element (Windows Media Player) in WPF

Tags: wpf, audio, visualization, mediaelement, playing

I just came across this requirement, could find this URL is of close match but the source downloaded is corrupted.
http://blogs.msdn.com/adam_nathan/archive/2005/10/24/using-com-interop-to-create-a-wpf-visualization-for-windows-media-player.aspx

Also how to add this visualization into Windows Media Player for playing audio files (like copying to proper folder for WMP 11 and change registry entries)

Any body else have the source code or other best way of doing this?

Thank you,
Sahridhayan

Answer (score 2):

I too found the link you posted and could not download the code.  I am trying to do the same thing and have posted a similar question here:

[C# Com Interop with Windows Media Player Visualisation (With Sample Code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060978/c-com-interop-with-windows-media-player-visualisation)

I have provided code to demonstrate my progress.  If I get no help I will just use C++ and interop to C# to perform my drawing (I'm not a C++ programmer and I want to use XNA for my effects).

Comment: The above link has now been resolved. It will get you as far as the plugin being functional. You will still need to perform the drawing.